# is it valid to have several separate class attributes on a HTML element?

Tags: html, validation

Is it valid HTML to use several separate class attributes in a HTML element?

Like this:

```
<div class="first-class" class="second-class">
</div>
```

I know it is possible to put several class names in a single class attribute, I just want to know is it allowed to do it another way, or is it absolutely forbidden?

Comment: If you know you can place several class names in one single class attribute, why would you bother having several class attributes?

Comment: @Andre: because it would be much more convenient in my situation - the code which generates the HTML would be more simple and clear to read.

Answer (score 5):

No, you must only have one class attribute. Multiple classes are separated by spaces.

```
<div class="first-class second-class"></div>
```

Here are references from the HTML Standard specifications:

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose
> names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

> This error occurs if the parser encounters an attribute in a tag that
> already has an attribute with the same name. The parser ignores all
> such duplicate occurrences of the attribute.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-duplicate-attribute